# Programmaticaly change attribute product type ( apply_to )

Tags: attributes

**Scenario:**
I have created a new product type (`configurable_b`), that extends the `configurable` product type.

The issue is that when I edit the product in the backend I cannot see many attributes.

The reason are:

- Many attribute are assigned specifically to `configurable` so I need to manually assign them to the `configurable_b` type.
- Even if the attribute is assigned to all product types, I need to save the attribute to display in my new `configurable_b`

Any way to fix this programmatically ?

Cycle on every attribute:

- assign it to `configurable_b` if they are assigned to configurable
- fix the issue with the attribute assigned to all product type

**NOTE**
I will accept also info that help me to create a script by myself, what I really miss is where the association to product type/attribute (apply_to) is stored in DB

Thansk

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you created a module to support your new product type.
You should write an install/upgrade script for your module that changes the `apply_to` of the attributes you need to be available for your product type also.
Make an array with all the attributes you need and run this script:

```
<?php

/* @var $installer Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup*/
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();
$newType =  'configurable_b';

$attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
    ->getItems();

foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    $applyTo = explode(',', $installer->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attribute->getAttributeCode(), 'apply_to'));

    if ( in_array('configurable', $applyTo) && !in_array($newType, $applyTo)) {
        $applyTo[] = $newType;
        $installer->updateAttribute('catalog_product', $attribute->getAttributeCode(), 'apply_to', join(',', $applyTo));
    }
}

$installer->endSetup();
```

**NOTE:**
The installer class need to be `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup` or a derivate

Comment: @Fra. You may want to make the installer be an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup` instead of `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup `. The `core` one does not have the method `updateAttribute`. Or make it at least `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup`